# OpenGL ES 1.1 reporting 0x0500 error

Tags: opengl-es

A simple question, does the error code 0x0500 mean anything besides there was an error?

Comment: Are your textures drawing white or is nothing showing up at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "GL_INVALID_ENUM" -- somewhere you passed an invalid GLenum.  This is defined in the gl.h header file.  Indeed--it's not very helpful.

EDIT: My strategy in dealing with these errors it to surround OpenGL calls with a macro that asserts everything is ok (glGetError() GL_NO_ERROR).  These get compiled out for performance tests.

Comment: What I think makes it worse, is I was hoping this would be the thing to tell me why my textures aren't drawing. Sadly it isn't.

Comment: I know!  There are never any clear answers!  I wish there was a glGetErrorString() so that drivers could leave error messages but alas I have scanned the gl.h file multiple times and found nothing.

Comment: [2014-08-20 13:15:29 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glActiveTexture:145 error 0x500

How to fix the previous error