# Cocos2D: openGL-es becoming transparent over UIView

Tags: opengl-es, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, opacity, transparent

For reasons outside the capabilities of Cocos2D, I needed to make it transparent and show UIView's behind it.

This works fine except under a certain circumstance.  When a sprite's opacity becomes more transparent, it makes everything else in Cocos2D drawn under it become transparent for some reason which makes my UIViews show through.

Shown here on the first image is water tiles, drawn in Cocos2D with a UIView of the mountain and the sky showing under it. The second image is the same thing except in Cocos2D there's a black sprite covering the whole screen at half opacity, which for some reason, makes the UIView under it show through.  Where this is most visible in my example is the mountain showing through the water tiles.

[image: No transparent image applied over Cocos2D]

[image: Transparent image applied over Cocos2D]

My delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching code is as follows:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application 
{
    // Init the window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Try to use CADisplayLink director
    // if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                                   depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        ];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

    glView.opaque = NO;

#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
#else
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
#endif

    [director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];


    //color/gradient BG

    bgLayer = [ColorBGView createGradientWithName:@"darkCave"];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    [viewController.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];


    // add custom parallax view

    parallaxView = [[ParallaxView alloc] init];
    parallaxView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [viewController.view insertSubview:parallaxView atIndex:1];

    [parallaxView release];


    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    [viewController.view insertSubview:glView atIndex:2];
    viewController.view.opaque = YES;
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    // make the View Controllers childs of the main window
    window.rootViewController = viewController;


    foregroundLabelView = [[ForegroundLabelView alloc] init];
    foregroundLabelView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [viewController.view insertSubview:foregroundLabelView atIndex:3];
    foregroundLabelView.hidden = YES;

    [foregroundLabelView release];


    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888]; //

    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];


    // Removes the startup flicker
    [self removeStartupFlicker];

    // Run the intro Scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [BlankScene scene]];
}
```

Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.

Comment: "reasons outside the capabilities of Cocos2D" <- this intrigues me, I like to know more about that. Because in my experience, when someone asked me a difficult question and immediately sets aside the rationale for doing something unconventional as being "not part of the problem" in most cases that unconventional approach did turn out to be unnecessary because better solutions exist, making it unnecessary to solve the complex and unusual problem. Also any reason why you're still using cocos2d 1.x?

Comment: I've been working on the game for a year and half and much of Cocos2D has been heavily edited.  I could maybe adopt many of the updates, but as now I found it unnecessary. Part of the reason I'm using a UIView underneath is to have smooth scrolling parallax backgrounds  while scene transitions take place. Otherwise if I used Cocos2D's parallax BG's, a new one would appear part way on top of another and out of sync while a scene transition occurs.

Comment: Hmmm I don't see where you set the glClearColor, this could be the issue. It should be all 0. Changing the overlay sprite's blendFunc might also be revealing.

Comment: Thanks, where should I put that in?

Comment: Oh, I was inferring from the rather simple screenshot that it must be a new project. :)
To fix the scene change issue I would simple not have changed scenes but animated layers in and out, retaining the scene with background scrolling throughout the entire game.

Comment: glClearColor(0,0,0,0); right after opaque = NO. And blendFunc is a CCSprite property. For experimenting and GL_ blend constants this site is helpful: http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php

Comment: I tried the glClearColor thing more than a few times, but I added it again.  I've been playing around with the black overlay's blendFunc and tried this (*sprite).blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }; with no change.

Comment: LeanCocos2D - I got it to work! I want you to answer so I can mark it as correct. I have a new issue now however: I get the error flooding my console output "OpenGL error 0x0500 in -[EAGLView swapBuffers]" I have set my spriteSheet, opposed to my sprite to this blend function (*spriteSheet).blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc) { GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA };

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704828/opengl-es-1-1-reporting-0x0500-error Could indicate that one of the blend modes you used isn't supported in OpenGL ES (1.1).

Comment: Thanks that was it.  I used (*spriteSheet).blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc) { GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA }; instead and it works without errors.

Please answer so I can mark it correct!